# Can websites see the Google account I'm logged into?

Tags: google, internet

If I go on a website, can the owner see what Google and Youtube account I use (on the same browser or not) even if I don't give that information away?

I ran one of those tests from [privacy.net](https://privacy.net/analyzer/) and it showed me that they knew I was logged on both Gmail and Youtube. But can they see which account?

Comment: i think this might help https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81114/how-can-i-hide-my-logged-in-sessions-from-other-websites/81115#81115

Comment: The best short answer is "sometimes".  A longer answer would depend on privacy measures in your browser and if you or (google, facebook, others) have shared your account details enough to match the account.